# Python logger.debug converting arguments to string without logging

Tags: python, logging, optimization

I'm optimizing a Python program that performs some sort of calculation. It uses NumPy quite extensively. The code is sprinkled with `logger.debug` calls (logger is the standard Python log object).

When I run cProfile I see that Numpy's function that converts an array to string takes 50% of the execution time. This is surprising, since there is no handler that outputs messages as the DEBUG level, only INFO and above.

Why is the logger converting its arguments to string even though nobody is going to use this string? Is there a way to prevent it (other than not performing the logger calls)?

Comment: Quick but hack-ish sounding solution that come to mind: include an if-guard, along the lines of `if logger.level <= logging.DEBUG: logger.debug(myBigArray)` (maybe not the exact syntax, but hopefully you get the idea)

Comment: Upon closer inspection, at least in `python3.4`, looking inside `logging.__init__.py`, it looks like it checks `logger.isEnabledFor(DEBUG)` (or whatever level) before calling the internal `logger._log(...)` function, so I don't see how or where it would be converting the array to a string. Are you calling it like: `logger.debug("My big array %s", myBigArray)` (which should not turn it into a string just yet) OR like `logger.debug("My big array " + str(myBigArray))` (which would force stringification to happen before `logger.debug` is even called)?

Comment: I'm calling logger.debug(array)

Comment: Shoot, I was really hoping the accidental stringification was the issue; it shouldn't be doing anything with `array` until it's check `.isEnabledFor(...)`.

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to tell what's happening, but looking at the source code for `logging.__init__.py` for both Python2.7 and Python3.4 (what I had lying around) shows that a call to `logger.debug(...)` for example, looks like:

```
if self.isEnabledFor(DEBUG):
    self._log(DEBUG, msg, args, **kwargs)
```

Which implies that if `DEBUG` isn't enabled, the `logger` isn't going to do any processing on any of the arguments.

One quick note, that I've burned myself on before though, is that you may be accidentally building the string before ever calling `logging.debug(...)`. Note the difference:

```
logger.debug("My big array: %s" % myBigArray) ## DON'T DO THIS
logger.debug("My big array: %s", myBigArray)  ## much better
```

The difference is the first line does the string-formatting before it ever even gets into `logger.debug` - you're passing in a single argument, which is a (potentially large) string. The second line, on the other hand, will do the string-formatting only if `DEBUG` is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use `logger.debug('%s', myArray)` rather than `logger.debug(myArray)`. The first argument is expected to be a format string (as all the documentation and examples show) and is not assumed to be computationally expensive. However, as @dwanderson points out, the logging will actually only happen if the logger is enabled for the level.

Note that you're not *forced* to pass a format string as the first parameter - you can pass a proxy object that will return the string when `str()` is called on it (this is also documented). In your case, that's what'll probably do the array to string conversion.

If you use logging in the manner that you're supposed to (i.e. as documented), there shouldn't be the problem you describe here.

Comment: I have a suspicion that this might be right, but I'd also be a little surprised because it doesn't look like the code does anything with the `args` and `**kwargs` until after checking `.isEnabledFor()`. Meaning - sure, maybe the first thing it does with the proxy object is turn it into a string, but I still would have hoped that this happened *after* the enable-check. But, I didn't have time to test/prove it.

Comment: Yeah, just checked: made a `Foo` class, whose `__str__` method printed to console before returning a `str`, made a `logger` with a `handler` set to `logging.WARN` (the default), and called `logger.debug(someFoo)`, which didn't write anything to console. So I don't think this particular tweak should make a difference, unfortunately.

Comment: @dwanderson Yes, I mentioned in my answer that logging will only happen if enabled for the level, but it's still good practice to follow the correct approach. Without seeing the entire logging config in use, there's no way of telling exactly what's going on.

Comment: I guess I'm confused, because the end of your post says "if you use logging correctly, you won't have your issue", but in your comment, you admit that your "solution" will not help the OP solve their problem. I agree that good practice is important to follow, I'm undecided if I agree that providing a format string like in your example is actually best practice (but that's tangential), and I'm positive that your suggestion does not help the OP.

Comment: @dwanderson Perhaps I misspoke when I said that, but I can tell you that the logging package interprets the first argument as either a format string or a proxy object on which `str()` will provide the format string. Whether or not that will solve this particular issue, it's still worth pointing out the correct (i.e. as designed/documented) way of using logging. BTW I upvoted your answer, as I think it's helpful. No way to know more about the problem unless the questioner posts more information.