# Python, how to avoid argument evaluation for logging statements below current level

Tags: python, logging, optimization, arguments

Suppose i have a statement like this

```
logging.debug('%r', do_really_expensive_computation())
or
logging.debug('%r', find_my_object().do_really_expensive_computation())
```

When logging level is set above `DEBUG` it will not log, but it will still evaluate the arguments before calling `logging.debug()` and execute `do_really_expensive_computation()` also `find_my_object()` could be quite heavy.

Is there any **good pattern** to skip all computation involved in logging when below current level?

Comment: `if logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG): do_expensive()`. For more details checkout the official python documentation https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/logging.html#optimization

Comment: Thanks, that could be the least painful way of doing it.

Comment: Looks like this have been asked before several times, just with different wording. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377020/python-how-to-do-lazy-debug-logging
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411265/python-logger-debug-converting-arguments-to-string-without-logging

Answer (score 8):

One approach is to create a helper class with a `__repr__` method that returns the value of a given callback function, and pass to the logger an instance of the helper class initialized with the expensive function object for a lazy evaluation:

```
class r:
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.callback())
```

so that:

```
import logging

def expensive():
    print('this is expensive')
    return 1

print('debug:')
logging.debug('%r', r(expensive))
print('error:')
logging.error('%r', r(expensive))
```

outputs:

```
debug:
error:
this is expensive
ERROR:root:1
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this using f-strings? I tried `logging.debug(f'{r(expensive)!r}')` but `expensive()` is always evaluated.

Comment: You're welcome. No, you can't use an f-string for the purpose because all expressions in curly brackets of an f-string must be fully evaluated before the final string object is passed to `logging.debug` for logging.

Comment: The `repr()` call changes some return values like strings. I think the last line of the class should be simply `return self.callback()`